# how to merge into master using git and visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, github

I want to merge from a brench into master using vs2022, in this pic pbackend-595 is the brench with the implementation of new task, i want to update master with the new implementation.

[image]

but clicking on pbackend-595 it is only proposed to merge origin\pbackend-595 to pbackend-595 accepting it say 0 files affected, in fact the 2 files are the same

[image]

under dwa it's only enabled the item marge master into pbackend-595 , clicking 0 files affected.

[image]

clicking on pbackend-595 under dwa merge is disabled

[image]

what's the way to copy pbackend-595 into master in local and remote both?

visual studio 2022

Comment: Git is always merging *into* the currently checked out branch. So check out `master` first, then right-clicking should give you the right options.